# How to share my media over the internet?

Tags: macos, internet, media, dlna

I have a significant media library (video, audio, photos, etc...).  It's all sitting on a 2TB external drive connected to a MacMini.  The MacMini shares the media to devices within my house via a DLNA server solution ([PS3 Media Server](http://ps3mediaserver.blogspot.com/)).  It works great.

Now that I've gotten a really fast internet connection (5MB up), I'd like to be able to listen to my music when I am at work, for instance.  Or perhaps to my iPhone/Android when I am on the go.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For music, check out **[Audiogalaxy](http://www.audiogalaxy.com/)**.

> Audiogalaxy's new cloud music player puts all your music and playlists at your fingertips from any computer, iOS or Android device. No syncing, no copying...

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten a lot of use out of [AirVideo Server/Player](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/index.html;jsessionid=D1C94BAF4C4F7A6916AC11593CD67458) for videos. It doesn't allow you to stream to a computer, but the iOS clients are great. It also has the added benefit of live conversion, so your video files don't necessarily have to be in a format at iTunes can play.